# Лексические нормы

Tags: плеоназм

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно перефразировать предложение с лексическими ошибками.
Здесь, как я считаю, плеоназм, но, возможно, я что-то не заметила.

Читать газету - одно удовольствие. Цветная и красочная, она не утомляет длинными статьями.

Заранее благодарна)

Comment: @lfhmz, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Она (цветная,) не утомляет длинными статьями и красочно иллюстрирована.
Цветной газету есть смысл называть, если в ней применяется ещё и цветной шрифт, иначе достаточно упомянуть о цветных иллюстрациях ("красочно" уже указывает на то, что они цветные); в первое предложение полезно добавить местоимение "эту".

Comment: В оригинале есть местоимение " эту".

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, плеоназма нет. Вернее, он возможен, только если газета одноцветная, но не черная:

*цветная и красочная = окрашенная в один яркий цвет + яркая.*

В другом значении:

*цветная и красочная = разноцветная + яркая.*

*Яркая и красочная = насыщенного тона + выполненная в красках.*

А если вкладывать другой смысл, возникает плеоназм:

*Яркая и красочная = насыщенного тона + яркая.*

Тут другая проблема. Предложение со странной структурой: *Цветная и красочная, она не утомляет длинными статьями.*

Обособленные определения в препозиции имеют добавочное обстоятельственное значение (причинное, условное, уступительное и т. п.) и могут быть заменены придаточным предложением.

*Низенький, коренастый, он обладал страшною силою в руках* (Он обладал силой, хоть и был низенький).

Газета не утомляет длинными статьями, хоть и красочная (?) / потому что красочная (?) / если красочная (?).

Нет никакой связи между красочностью и длиной статей.

Comment: Цветной -с окраской разных цветов; разноцветный, многоцветный.Красочный - выполненный красками, в красках. Если что-то выполнено красками, - значит оно цветное.

Comment: Следовательно - плеоназм.

Comment: Если "разноцветная + выполненная в красках", то да, плеоназм. А если "разноцветная + яркая", то не плеоназм. Пример неоднозначный, для учебника не подходит.

Comment: Да, Тат, вот здесь с вами соглашусь.

Comment: Краска может быть и белой, и чёрной.

Answer (score 0):

***Цветная и красочная,*** она не утомляет длинными статьями. Выделенное слова - плеонастичны. Возможно так: Будучи красочной - она не утомляет.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. )

Answer (score 0):

Здесь нет плеоназма. Слова "цветной" и "красочный" не являются синонимами. Первое прилагательное относительное (говорит о том, что газета не чёрно-белая), а второе — качественное (говорит о яркости, выразительности). Газета может быть цветная, но не красочная, например, если цвета блеклые.

Comment: Второе значение слова "красочный" - выполненный красками, в красках. 

3.Яркий, выразительный. К. пример. К-ое описание. К-ая речь. Цветной -  С окраской разных цветов; разноцветный, многоцветный. Как видите, это слова-синонимы, и данном случаи они плеонастичны.

Comment: Нет, это не синонимы. Первое значение прилагательного "красочный" связано с веществом (лако-красочные материалы), второе связано с яркостью, насыщенностью. И то, и другое не являются синонимами к значению слова "цветной", которое говорит о наличии цветов как таковых.

Comment: Уважаемый Пересвет! Составитель задания учитель русского языка и литературы высшей категории Бабенкова Л. А.

Comment: Какое значение имеет, кто придумал задание? Давайте говорить по существу.

Ожегов:
>>    КРА́СОЧНЫЙ
    1. см. краска.
    2. Отличающийся яркими красками (в 3 знач.), **яркий**. Красочная расцветка. Красочная речь.

>>ЦВЕТНОЙ
1. **Окрашенный**, имеющий какой-н. цвет или цвета (кроме чёрного и белого). Цветная обложка. Цветные металлы (в отличие от чёрных железа и его сплавов). Ц. фильм, цветное телевидение (не чёрно-белые).

Что видим? Нет пересекающихся значений.

Comment: Ушаков:
>> ЦВЕТНО́Й
Окрашенный в какой-нибудь цвет, **не черный и не белый**. Цветное платье. Цветная фотография. Цветные металлы (название всех металлов, за исключением железа и его сплавов). Цветное кино.

>>КРАСОЧНЫЙ
    1. прил. к краска (спец.). Красочная промышленность.
    2. Колоритный, яркий, выразительный, характерный (книжн.). Красочный язык Гоголя. Красочная оркестровка.

Вновь нет пересекающихся значений.

Выводы. Плеоназма нет, но лучше было бы написать "яркий и цветной".